# Accessing data from previous loader?

Tags: remix.run

In remix.run, is it possible to expose data from one loader to the next? I have tried with contexts, but didn't understand how to get this to work.

I have the following structure;

```bash
root.tsx
thing.tsx
thing/index.tsx
thing/other.tsx
thing/component.tsx
```

(could in theory be deeper too)

All of `thing/index.tsx`, `thing/other.tsx`, `thing/component.tsx` need the same data which I want to load only once in `thing.tsx`, and pass it to all the sub-elements. I assume this is possible to do, but my search-foo failed me.

---

Step by step of what I'm thinking. Please correct me if this is the wrong approach with remix;

opens: https://example.com/thing/other

1. `root.tsx` runs, and does whatever is global on the site
2. `thing.tsx` runs loader and fetches some data, lets say `titleText`
3. `thing/other.tsx` runs loader, and needs the `titleText` also. fetches `titleText` from some kind of context
4. `thing/component.tsx` runs with `titleText` data provided by `thing/other.tsx`

Comment: After reading up some more, I do realize that some of the premise of remix.run is that the loaders will run in parallel. I will try to restructure my system based on this knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

It is actually possible to access the loader data of all your parent pages using the [`useMatches`](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-matches) hook.

And though I have not personally used it, there is the [shouldRevalidateFunction](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/should-revalidate), which will let you control when a loader should refresh data for a remix page.

With these 2 tools, you should be able to implement the behavior you desire.